# Handle billions of records with Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Happy Holiday!

I got some questions regarding huge table within Spanner.

Our database is running on cloud sql(mysql), one of the table has a few billions rows, frequently we join range of the table(pick by index) with another table with 1 million records. with proper index in place, so far performance is good enough. With more data coming in, we are considering to split the table into a few new tables and migrate database into Spanner for better scalability.

Misc Question:

1. Is spanner able to handle billions of records with true scalability?
2. One of my bad experience with MySQL was to add index on huge table, which could take days. Spanner has index back-filling feature, hopefully it can address the issue.  any real-life experience with this?
3. Comparing to MySQL, Spanner is missing convenient features like rename table, column etc, does that impact your work much?
4. any other potential problem on maintenance of the huge table.

Any experience on using Spanner with huge data is greatly appreciated!